# Dashのバージョンを知るにはどうすれば良い？

Tags: dash

Dash シェルのバージョンはどうしたら分かりますか？

`man dash` には書かれておらず、`dash --version` や `dash -v` を試しましたが出力されません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

パッケージ管理ツールを使っていれば、パッケージのメタデータにバージョン情報がついていることがあります。

例

- Ubuntu：`apt-cache policy dash` や `dpkg -s dash`
- Red Hat 系や CentOS など：`rpm -q dash`

参考

- [how to tell the version number of dash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36660724/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- [How to find the version of the Dash shell on Ubuntu /bin?](https://askubuntu.com/q/283134/644471) -- Ask Ubuntu